# Using PosExplorer GetDevice WITH COM1

Tags: c#, .net, printing, opos

I'm trying to use the OPOS for NET applications But I don't know how to use it with a fiscal printer that is connected to port COM1.

If I use an external library like this "http://www.impresoras-fiscales.com.ar/" the printer prints.

But I want to create my own library/application.
So for that as per the comments I read, I need to have a logical name for the printer, but currently I don't have it and it is working with the other library.

I need to know how I can connect me to the printer as the other library using just the port COM number.

This is the code that I use with the other library:

```
nError = imprimir.IF_OPEN("192.168.0.5", 555);
            //nError = imprimir.IF_OPEN(oPunto.url, Convert.ToInt32(oPunto.puerto));
            nError = imprimir.IF_WRITE("@PONEENCABEZADO|1|Vendedor: " + oEmpleado.Nombre);
            if (IdMesa != 0)
            {
                nError = imprimir.IF_WRITE("@PONEENCABEZADO|2|Mesa: " + IdMesa);
            }
            else
            {
                nError = imprimir.IF_WRITE("@PONEENCABEZADO|2|Venta para llevar");
            }
            nError = imprimir.IF_WRITE("@PONEENCABEZADO|5|");
            nError = imprimir.IF_WRITE("@TIQUEABRE|C|");
foreach-->
nError = imprimir.IF_WRITE("@TIQUEITEM|" + DescProducto + "|" + Cantidad + "|" + Total + "|" + Iva + "|M|1|0|0|");

nError = imprimir.IF_WRITE("@TIQUEPAGO|Su Pago es de: |" + Total + "|T|");
        nError = imprimir.IF_WRITE("@TIQUECIERRA|T|");
```

In this case, I'm using the library to connect me by the network (see the IP) but I just need a desktop application that can print fiscal receipt.
In the client computer, I install a small application where I set the COM port.

So, I need to have the same behavior but using my own code. Could you help me... Please see the way I connect to the printer just using the COM1. I need something similar

Comment: Post the code you have already tried.

Comment: I still don't see any .Net code. And I can't read spanish so I can't make much sense of the site sorry. You should post the code you have already tried and what error message you get.

Comment: Using an external library, everything works fine, there isn't any error. The thing is that I want to do it by myself (to not depend on other people).
But I don't know how to start with this, because every site says that I need to add a Logical Name, But that is not the idea, I just want to do it using the port COM as this library does.

Comment: I _think_ what you need to is install the printer on the COM port as usual then map an IP address to this COM port, then use the above library to write to the IP address. I'm suprised no one from printing has picked up on this. Take a look at this page: http://www.edimax.us/html/Faq/FAQ_PS_standardtcpip.htm - do you see 'add port' anywhere? I think you need to install as usual then add a TCP/IP port.